# ExtJs: TreeLoader: static data is n't working but why?

Tags: javascript, extjs, treeview

I have separated my screen into 4.I like to use the same static variable object for all the 4 screen divisions.May be update the variable object from one screen division it have to affect all the other screed divisions

the left side will be tree and the right side will be a explorer

```js
      Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : '/myapp/forms/getTreeObject',
            params : {
                fileName : 'text',
                fileType : 'folder',
                rootPath : 'path'
            },
            success : function(result) {
                // Ext.Msg.alert("INFO",result.responseText);
                fileSysObj = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
                userSettingPanel.tpl.overwrite(userSettingPanel.body,
                        fileSysObj);
            }
        });


        var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
            useArrows : true,
            animate : true,
            enableDD : true,
            collapseFirst :false,
            containerScroll : true,
            border : false,
            id : 'workspace',
            root : new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
                childNodes :fileSysObj,
                text : 'Workspace'
            }),
            loader : new Ext.tree.TreeLoader()
        });
```

<-- language: lang-js -->

Comment: the ajax request is get fired later after the tree's root is got appended.can anyone tell me i like to make the ajax request before this happenns

Comment: Is the structure of `fileSysObj` a tree node collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chau yes!

@all i have add the tree object with object level instead of array level. thanks for you support to everyone